# Get all the values from the second column in table selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am using the following xpath to get all the values from the second column

```
//table[contains(@id,'DataGridemplis')]//tr/td[2]
```

Is it possible to skip the first row? I need to exclude the first row from the results.

Comment: Was there an url to test with? Might be able to use css selector of `#DataGridemplis tr:nth-child(n+3) td:nth-child(2)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The URL is private and needs credentials to log in.

Comment: Does the above work?

Comment: Yes, this works too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched and could figure it out

```
//table[contains(@id,'DataGridemplis')]//tr[position()>1]/td[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use nth-child css selectors. Ignore the first row using an n+3 within nth-child, for the tr, then use 2 to get the second column tds

```
.find_elements_by_css_selector("DataGridemplis tr:nth-child(n+3) td:nth-child(2)")
```